# How to disable the default closing behaviour from infoWindow in OsmBonusPack?

Tags: android, osmdroid

By default the OsmBonusPack infoWindow bubble closes when I tab the bubble.

How can I disable the default closing behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own InfoWindow:

```
MarkerInfoWindow myInfoWindow = new MarkerInfoWindow(layoutResId, map);
```

Set to its view the TouchListener you want. 
For instance, to do nothing:

```
View v = myInfoWindow.getView();
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then give this infoWindow to all your markers:

```
myMarker.setInfoWindow(myInfoWindow);
```